# Windows Vista Home Premium upgrade to Windows Vista Ultimate

Tags: windows-vista, upgrade

I've recently bought a Dell laptop with Windows Vista Home Premium (Italian). I knew that I can't install Microsoft Reporting Server 2005 on it because Home Premium doesn't support Windows authentication.

Then, I bought a Windows Vista Ultimate upgrade through the Microsoft Store but I can't do the upgrade because the installation disc is in a different language.

Why? How do I upgrade my version of Vista Home?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932006

Answer (score 1):

http://www.creative-wisdom.com/computer/windows/different_lang.shtml

Answer (score 0):

You are asking a difficult question, solely because the only way to get a real answer would be to phone Microsoft and ask.

It is a business decision taken by Microsoft. They do not include the language packs on the discs, and because of the various different regulation across the world, will provide specific media to specific countries. I would suspect when you purchased your copy of Windows, it should have given you the option of choosing the correct language.

Arguably this is not the way Apple or others do provide software, but I would suspect the slew of legal problems Microsoft had in the past, specifically with Europe and the IE issues in the past, causing the creation of the K edition of Windows, for example, would have be a big reason for this decision.

Comment: true enough, a simple phone call will yield the answer to this question. these guys are usually very helpful. +1